# Derivative of the norm of a second order tensor w.r.t. the tensor

Tags: analysis

I came across this derivative in a paper:

$\frac{\partial{\|{A}\|}}{\partial A} = \frac{A}{\|A\|}$

where A is a rank 2 tensor. And I wonder what is the definition of this norm. I believe it is not a general expression.

One more thing, what would be the second derivative if this expression is correct:

$\frac{\partial^2{\|{A}\|}}{\partial A^2} = ?$

Thank you all.

Comment: ...which paper?

Comment: The norm is not going to be differentiable at $A=0$; also, your notation is mixed-up; e.g., if you had vectors, then $\|x\|_2$ is subdifferentiable at $x=0$, but of course not differentiable. Also, I think this question might fit math.SE well (after you've clarified the notation, however).

Comment: @carlo: The paper is about recrystallization in polycrystals and A is there the rate of plastic strain.

Comment: @survit: that is my question. There was no subscript so I could know the type of the norm.

Comment: I second Carlo's request: which paper? As $A$ is a rank 2 tensor, it is possible that the notation $\dots/A$ means $\dots A^{-1}$ where $A$ is interpreted as a matrix (or an element of an algebra). But then again, it can also mean something entirely different. You really need to give more information.

Comment: Really sorry guys, I had a mistake in the question which I corrected ($\frac{\partial{\|{A}\|}}{\partial A} = \frac{A}{\|A\|}$). The paper you can find here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgrb.50125/abstract (See equations 46d, 55 and 60).
As I mentioned $A$ (a rank 2 tensor) is there the rate of the plastic strain ($\dot{\epsilon_p}$). Again, $A$ is a second order tensor not anything else.
If you need more information please let me know. Thank you very much again.